# Un-minimizing an app with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to write a script to un-minimize an app that was previously minimized to dock.
Problem is, I can't find the relevant property. I've tried `miniaturized` and `collapsed` but neither the window nor the process seems to have those?

The app I use (for testing) is Zipeg, a free packing tool.

I've also tried to click the button which happily MINIMIZES the app, but gives me an error when running on an already minimized app to restore it, probably because no window is visible. This script is below.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Zipeg"
        click button 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

The script I used to list properties is below.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Zipeg"
        get properties
        tell window 1
            get properties
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
tell app (path to frontmost application as text)
    try
        set miniaturized of windows to false -- most apps
    end try
    try
        set collapsed of windows to false -- Finder
    end try
end tell
```

This unminimizes a single window if *Minimize windows into application icon* isn't checked:

```
try
    tell app "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
        click (last UI element of list 1 where role description is "minimized window dock item")
    end tell
end try
```

If all windows of an app are minimized, `reopen` unminimizes the first one:

```
tell app "TextEdit"
    reopen -- unminimizes the first minimized window or makes a new default window
    activate -- makes the app frontmost
end tell
```

Comment: reopen was what I waas searching for. Thank you!

Comment: How do you minimize all windows?

Answer (score 1):

if you `tell application "App" to activate` it will un-minimize a window if all windows are minimized.

Comment: Nope, does not work for the app. Also tried with ITunes (tell application "iTunes" to activate) and doesn't work there either... It activates and shows the application's menu, but no window.

Comment: Hmmm… it doesn't. I thought `activate` was supposed to be equivalent to clicking on the Dock icon.

Comment: @CajunLune `reopen` is the equivalent of clicking a Dock icon. If there's no open windows, it unminimizes the first minimized window or makes a new default window.

Comment: @Lri your comment solved my problem and should definitely be an answer...

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set index of window 1 to 1
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines.

```
tell application "Finder" to set collapsed of every window to false
```

Comment: As I wrote above, the window in question has no "collapsed" property. The code above works for Finder but my app has another set of properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is a script that un-minimizes the previously minimized window of **the currently focused application**.

```
tell application id ("com.apple.systemevents")  ¬
  to tell (process 1 where it is frontmost) ¬
  to tell (windows whose attribute named "AXMinimized"'s value is true) ¬
  to if (it exists) then set the value of its attribute named "AXMinimized" of item 1 to false
```

I found this script more useful than the accepted answer.

This script is not written by me, and you can find more related scripts [here](https://talk.automators.fm/t/unminimize-windows-of-the-current-application/12360/5?u=hugh).